# Bundling CSS into native web components without duplicating the style with Webpack 5

Tags: webpack

I have native web components that I need to bundle with Webpack 5.

I'll describe an example setup I have which should make it clear. I have a folder structure like:

- src

  - ui

    - uicomponent.js
    - uicomponent.css
    - ...other web components
  - css

    - shared.css
    - ...other shared style files

Ideally the ui-component would just have a style tag with @import in the shadow root to the uicomponent.css. (I can't use adoptedStyleSheets due to browser compatibility as I'm aware constructable stylesheets are the most optimal solution).

I believe the solution is related to lazyStyleTag, but I'm not sure. I can't find any real world examples except this snippet in the docs: https://webpack.js.org/loaders/style-loader/#function

##### uicomponent.js:

```js
import uiComponentStyle from './uicomponent.css';

export default class UIComponent extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
        uiComponentStyle.use({ target: this.shadowRoot }); // Creates a style tag and strips @import lines
        // ...
    }
}
customElements.define('ui-component', UIComponent);
```

##### uicomponent.css:

```css
@import '../css/shared.css'; // I have a few of these shared stylesheets
:host {
    display: flex;
}
```

I thought at first maybe I could use:

```json
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.css$/i,
            exclude: [
                path.resolve(__dirname, "src/ui")
            ],
            use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"]
        },
        {
            test: /\.css$/i,
            include: [
                path.resolve(__dirname, "src/ui")
            ],
            use: [
                {
                    loader: "style-loader",
                    options: {
                        injectType: "lazyStyleTag",
                        insert: function insertIntoTarget(element, options) {
                            var parent = options.target || document.head;
                            parent.appendChild(element);
                        },
                    },
                },
                "css-loader"
            ]
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

But that apparently doesn't process the @import statements correctly for web components. (I'm guessing it pulls them out into the document head rather than inserting them into the shadowRoot as would be expected). Trying to move the @import lines out and use the .use(...) syntax wouldn't work with the above configuration since the '../css' folder isn't processed with lazyStyleTag. This leads me to think I should be using the lazyStyleTag for everything. That seems odd though because it breaks every usage of `import './css/shared.css'` that would automatically create a style tag in the head. I'd need to change everything to do:

```js
import sharedStyle from './css/shared.css';
sharedStyle.use();
```

I don't see such conventions in other projects so it seems like I'm on the wrong track. The webpack.config.js would look like:

```json
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.css$/i,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: "style-loader",
                    options: {
                        injectType: "lazyStyleTag",
                        insert: function insertIntoTarget(element, options) {
                            var parent = options.target || document.head;
                            parent.appendChild(element);
                        },
                    },
                },
                "css-loader"
            ]
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

In any case if I try the above it strips the `@import '../css/icons.css';` out of the uicomponent.css which isn't what I want to happen.

My question is what's the standard way to bundle web component styling in Webpack 5?

Ideally I don't want to just copy and paste the CSS file into every web component in a style tag. I have pages with thousands of instances of the web component (think trees with checkboxes) and I've noticed this consumes a lot of memory if done that way as the style shows up in every shadow root instance. Is it even possible to use @import with a bundle or would I need to duplicate the css files to a folder and use like an import filter with css-loader just for my web components?

edit:

A comment below mentions using the construct-style-sheets-polyfill package. I changed webpack.config.js rule using these docs: https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader/ to:

```json
{
    test: /\.css$/i,
    use: [
        "style-loader",
        {
            loader: "css-loader",
            options: {
                exportType: "css-style-sheet"
            }
        }
    ]
},
```

Then I put `import 'construct-style-sheets-polyfill';` at the top of my entry point.

I pulled out the @imports into their own `import sharedStyle from '../css/shared.css';` lines. Then I changed the uicomponent.js files to:

```js
import sharedStyle from '../css/shared.css' assert { type: "css" };
import uiComponentStyle from './uicomponent.css' assert { type: "css" };

export default class UIComponent extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
        this.shadowRoot.adoptedStyleSheets = [sharedStyle, uiComponentStyle];
        // ...
    }
}
customElements.define('ui-component', UIComponent);
```

Without the "assert" error I get is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to set the 'adoptedStyleSheets' property on 'ShadowRoot': Failed to convert value to 'CSSStyleSheet'.
```

It's like the exportType is ignored in webpack? Can I use exportType with the polyfill?

Am I supposed to have two rules? I tried something like:

```json
{
    test: /\.css$/i,
    use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"]
},
{
    assert: { type: "css" },
    loader: "css-loader",
    options: {
        exportType: "css-style-sheet",
    },
},
```

With the assert css it says:

```
ERROR in ./src/ui/uicomponent.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1]!./src/ui/uicomponent.css)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js):
CssSyntaxError

(1:1) .../src/ui/component.css Unknown word

> 1 | // Imports
    | ^
  2 | import ___CSS_LOADER_API_SOURCEMAP_IMPORT___ from "../../node_modules/css-loader/dist/runtime/sourceMaps.js";
  3 | import ___CSS_LOADER_API_IMPORT___ from "../../node_modules/css-loader/dist/runtime/api.js";
```

edit 2:
So if I use:

```json
{
    test: /\.css$/i,
    use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"]
},
```

and:

```js
import sharedStyle from '!css-loader?exportType=css-style-sheet!../css/shared.css' assert { type: "css" };
import uiComponentStyle from '!css-loader?exportType=css-style-sheet!./uicomponent.css' assert { type: "css" };

export default class UIComponent extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
        this.shadowRoot.adoptedStyleSheets = [sharedStyle, uiComponentStyle];
        // ...
    }
}
customElements.define('ui-component', UIComponent);
```

That works! Is that what I'm supposed to be doing? Seems verbose.

I notice in Firefox when it falls back it inserts style tags which have a severe performance penalty when loading lots of web components. I'm guessing I'd need to generate URL.createObjectURL for each CSS file and change the fallback to create @import statements. I wonder why the polyfill doesn't do that?

Comment: Use constructed stylesheets, along with the [polyfill](https://github.com/calebdwilliams/construct-style-sheets).

Comment: @connexo I tried that polyfill and it didn't work. Is there a tutorial or example for the setup with Webpack with that? I updated my post to include what I tried. I'm probably missing something simple.

Comment: The polyfill cannot fix missing CSS module scripts keyword `assert { type: 'css' }`. Instead, simply import your CSS into a `style` string, and create the constructed stylesheet using `const sheet = new CSSStyleSheet; sheet.replaceSync(style);`.

Comment: @connexo the solution I put at the bottom of my post seems to work in Chrome and falls back in Firefox to inserting style tags as expected. The "!css-loader?exportType=css-style-sheet!" seems to do the string to CSSStyleSheet work automatically.